# Can I background a running thread in the Slime (Swank Emacs)

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, slime, swank

I often find my self starting some long running process from the REPL and then wish I could carry on using the REPL for other tasks while it was running. **Can I use slime to background the current thread or start a new REPL control thread?** Starting an additional REPL buffer would be fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Hm, I somehow managed to miss the Clojure tag on your question. I would be very suprised if the solution below worked for Clojure, since, as you probably know, the Clojure community unfortunately (at least for those of us using Clojure *and* CL) maintains its own version of Slime. I won't delete the answer, because it might be helpful for CL programmers searching for this functionality.

Unless there is a similar solution for Clojure, which allows multiple REPLs multiplexed over a single socket, you could maybe just start a second Swank server by hand (from the `*inferior-lisp*` buffer) and connect to it via `slime-connect` as a workaround. (Can't test this ATM, since I stopped using Slime with Clojure a while ago.)

---

Did you try the `slime-mrepl` contrib? I have not actually used it myself, but a quick test worked for me under CCL/Win/Emacs 24.

I tested it like this: `M-x slime`, enter `(sleep 10)` in the REPL, switch buffer, `M-x slime-new-mrepl`.

Answer (score 2):

Please forgive me for a somewhat trite and non-slime specific answer; on the upside it will work with any clojure REPL.

When I know in advance  I am starting a long running task from the REPL then I start the computation using `future` and check with `future-done?` before deref-ing it.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question, but it might be helpful to realize that as long as `(slime-communication-style)` is `:spawn`, evaluations done using `C-x C-e` always spawn their own thread and can run in parallel to whatever is happening in the REPL thread.  Output (from `println` etc.) will appear in the REPL buffer.